# Opera12 browser support for WebGL

Tags: opera, webgl

I have enabled - enable webGL by entering Enable WebGL in opera:config by setting the value to 1, and Enable Hardware Acceleration similarly, then restart the browser - Opera 12 on Windows & tried to open - http://aleksandarrodic.com/p/jellyfish/.

This gives me an alert saying - Your browser failed to initialize WebGL.

Please guide me on - What's going wrong?

opera:gpu says :
Hardware acceleration Disabled
Direct3D 10 Backend not supported Could not load library
OpenGL Backend not supported Could not load library

But,same thing (http://aleksandarrodic.com/p/jellyfish/) works fine on Chrome!

Thanks 
Sneha

Comment: Open a new tab on opera and add as address `opera:gpu`. What does it say?

Comment: Hardware acceleration Disabled 
Direct3D 10 Backend not supported
Could not load library OpenGL
Backend not supported
Could not load library

Comment: Could it be that your GPU hardware is not good enough? (Sorry, that I can't define "good enough".)

Comment: but it works fine on Chrome!

Answer (score 3):

To support WebGl (or Hardware accelleration) browser must ensure compatibility with Video card drivers. This is done per card / per driver revision / per OS version (because they can be quite different).

The message that you are getting just means that your combination of Operating System, Graphic Card and Video Driver is not supported by Opera (*yet*). This might or might not change in future.

`but it works in Chrome` - all browsers are different ;) Especially in implementations of such experimental features as WebGL.